# Dynamic equivalent of TempData

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Microsoft introduced ViewBag in MVC3 which is the dynamic version of ViewData. Similarly is there a dynamic version of TempData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such dynamic version. But you could probably easily write an extension method that wraps the `TempDataDictionary` as a `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

Negative ghost rider but avoid the dynamic stuff if possible and use viewmodels as it is strongly typed and easier to follow